# Does commutator bracket satisfy Jacobi identity?

Tags: matrices, group-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras

Commutators (from physics background) are defined as $[X, Y]=XY-YX$.
Do they satisfy the Jacobi identity for free?

Comment: Yep! Try to verify it, it's only a few lines

Comment: expand out $[[x, y], z] + [[y, z], x] + [[z, x], y]$ using linearity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is even true in much greater generality. Algebra products $(x,y)\mapsto x\cdot y$ are called *Lie-admissible*, if
$$
[x,y]:=x\cdot y-y\cdot x
$$
satisfies the Jacobi identity. There is a large literature in physics and mathematics on these Lie-admissible algebras. One prominent example are pre-Lie algebras.
Here pre-Lie algebra means that we have
$$
(x,y,z)=(y,x,z)
$$
for all $x,y,z$, where $(x,y,z):=x\cdot (y\cdot z)-(x\cdot y)\cdot z$ denotes the associator. If this product is even associative, then clearly
$(x,y,z)=0=(y,x,z)$, so that the Jacobi identity holds for the commutator.

Answer (score 3):

Yes.  Indeed, if $X$ $Y$, and $Z$ are square matrices of the same size, then

$[X, Y], Z] + [[Y, Z], X] + [[Z, X], Y] = [(XY - YX), Z] + [(YZ - ZY), X] + [(ZX - XZ), Y]$
$= XYZ - YXZ - ZXY + ZYX + YZX - ZYX$
$-  XYZ + XZY + ZXY - XZY - YZX + YXZ = 0. \tag 1$

It is easy to see that this holds when $X$, $Y$, $Z$ are elements of any associative algebra; they needn't be matrices.

If the Jacobi identity isn't free, it certainly isn't expensive!